# Yandex bot in my website

Tags: magento-1.8, .htaccess, robots.txt

I have noticed that when I'm surfing my website, where it appears the `Waiting for www.whatever.com...` on the left-bottom corner from google chrome it appears suddenly a `Waiting for mc.yandex.com...` which I don't know why is it appearing there. I've googled it and it seems to be a bot that act as `google.analytics` does, but I don't want this from yandex. Is it possible to block it from `.htaccess`? I've tried doing:

```
BrowserMatchNoCase "yandex" bots
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from ALL
Deny from env=bots
```

But it still shows up. If there is any way for me to block it. How can I block this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a bot. This means that you have yandex metrika added to your source code. This is the same as google analytics.

It could be that some extension is adding it to your magento's output

Look for this piece in your source code: `new Ya.Metrika`

You can search through the files of your magento installation for this piece of code to find which extension is adding this

Comment: You are totally right, it was at the very end of my footer.phtml, I don't really know how it appeared there. Anyway, thank you! I was a little scared someone was trying to make my website go slower or something else.